# Cannot Create Custom InfoPath Form on my list

Tags: infopath, custom-form

I am trying to add a custom InfoPath form on a list which uses one of my custom content types. However, attempting to do so throws this complaint:

"Customizing the form for this content type is not supported."

I find it hard to believe you must only use Microsoft's content types in order to create custom InfoPath forms.

Comment: My problem might be related to this. My list and content type was defined using CAML. Now when I try to customize the form it's giving me "InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list. Missing equals sign between attribute and attribute value." My last resort might be to define the content type and list programmatically. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the content type is not set to be read-only. If it is read only, SharePoint will not allow you to change the field order or customize the InfoPath form.

1. Navigate to the list using the content type and go to list settings from the ribbon
2. Click on the content type in question (if you can't see them allow management of content types in the list's Advanced settings)
3. Click on Advanced settings on the content type screen
4. Validate that the setting for "Should this content type be read only?" is set to No.
5. Save your changes and try to customize the form again.

This was addressed in: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717706